# C# - Reading Russian text from a .txt file

Tags: c#-4.0, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, internationalization

I'm having a problem trying to read Russian characters from a .txt file. The text always becomes corrupt when I read it. The file encoding is UTF8.

Here's the code:

```
  TextReader reader = new StreamReader(deliveryLocation, Encoding.UTF8);
  translatedContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
  reader.Close();
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've tried using all the supported encodings, but the text is always corrupted?

Here's a sample of the text I need to read from the file:

> От таблиц выше мы см. чонсервной банкы тень и WinRunner брать3p
>   приблизительно такое же время настраивать и запускать цикл испытания в
>   будут немного NEOBXODIMO снимков экрана. Где более большой количество
>   снимков экрана NEOBXODIMO, время бранное для того чтобы запускать тень
>   чем время бранное для писания Кодего и для того чтобы выполнять оно в
>   WinRunner. Примечания инженера в его отчете что WinRunner требовать3s
>   сборка средства программирования под испытанием специально, котор
>   нужно подготовить работать с им, тогда как тень не делает. Каждый
>   ресурс включено страница должен иметь имя ШИЛА (ШИЛО будет языком
>   стержня клиента собственническим).

Comment: can you post a sample of the data to pastebin.com and give us a link to it?

Comment: The file encoding may be UTF-8, but are all its characters valid UTF-8? I've seen files in various encodings "converted" by just slapping on the UTF-8 BOM and calling it a day; alas, it isn't quite that simple.

Comment: but with some embedded Russian characters, right?

Comment: anyway, I'm going to sleep now, check for cp1251 and koi8_r as well as utf-16

Comment: This may be a good lead.


: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821118/how-to-read-cyrillic-symbols-from-a-txt-file-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(deliveryLocation, Encoding.Defaut);
  translatedContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
  reader.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello try the below to read Russian characters.

```
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(deliveryLocation, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
translatedContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
```

and try to open the output data in Notepad++ with Encoding format as Cyrillic-1251.

Regards,
Shambhu